# Reload existing angularJS page with stateParams intact

Tags: javascript, angularjs, state

I have a function that shows or hides a button in relation to a value pulled from an API

I load a record with a parameter of 'id' ($stateParams.id)

If this value is 1 a button appears that fires a function that sets it to 0
If this value is 0 a button appears that fires a function that sets it to 1

These functions work fine however after the functions fire I want to reload the existing page but have the button change dynamically. If I leave the page and come back, or set state.go to any other page the button is changing no problem

I am using the following to try and reload the page after the function fires but nothing happens.. not even an error

```
$state.go($state.current, {id : $stateParams.id}, {reload: true});
```

Comment: Do you really need to reload the entire page or just the button(s)?

Comment: Version of router? Have you tried {inherit:true}?

Comment: reloading just the button would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... that was easier than expected. Just used

```
$state.reload()
```